# MongoDB URI Configuration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using MongoDB URI (mongodb://user:pass@IP:27017/myDB?retryWrites=false&connectTimeoutMS=10000) configuration in Spring-boot. I observed approx every 5 min. Mongodb not responding for first hit, Second hit working fine. 
Some time getting this message "Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:8}]" in log.

**Java Configuration.**

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(prop.getDbConnectionUri()));
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
    log.info("Loging MongoDB Config Loging...");
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    return mongoTemplate;

}
```

Please suggest any other optional configuration required in Mongo URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many Changes,I fixed this problem by changing below system configuration. This is not related to mongo configuration.

1. Open sysctl.conf  by using  "sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf" command.
2. Change "net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 220".
3. Save Changes.
4. Run "sysctl --system" command.
5. And Restart your micro service.

Now Mongo Connection working fine.